# Rails4 Youtube uploader 401 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, youtube, youtube-data-api

i'am developing a rails4 application that uploads videos to youtube using the user's Google account credentials. I succeeded contacting the YoutubeDataApi to check user's credentials but when i try to push the Video to youtube servers it respond to with a 401 error : Token Invalid.

```
Started POST "/videos/get_upload_token" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-04 18:21:00 +0200
Processing by VideosController#get_upload_token as JSON
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"qisidAqdL5CjdfHbk20B6bS3DNYa1yjXn17Eos86TTVHAsP5j2WoR/FI08ptp04vGdWw3DLn/3HY6xt/Um2ztg==", "title"=>"sqdqs", "description"=>"dsqf"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 210ms

OAuth2::Error (<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Token invalid</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Token invalid</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
):
  app/controllers/videos_controller.rb:24:in `get_upload_token'
```

I'am using Youtube_it gem and oAuth2 to contact google.

Here is the GitHub link to my project : https://github.com/GhostGumm/Bubblz101

Any help or direction will be much appreciated, thank you :).